# JavaScript w/ Cordova Camera Plugin - Convert image FILE_URI to DATA_URL

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-camera

I am using the `cordova-plugin-camera` in order to access the camera in my hybrid app.
I need to capture the photo and send it for upload as base64.
When capturing a photo, I can specify the following:

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

which returns an image encoded as base64. However, DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors (as mentioned in the plugin's documentation). Because of this, my app crashes on weaker devices, so using `DATA_URL` is a no-go. Using the default `FILE_URI` should solve this problem, but my backend is configured to only accept base64 encoded images.

**My question is, is there a way to convert an image from FILE_URI to DATA_URL base64 encoding?**

Answer (score 0):

You could download the picture from the `FILE_URI` and then you'd have to render the image in a canvas and then from the canvas, get the base64 using the `canvas.toDataURL` method.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your **FILE_URI** to base64 data which is **DATA_URL**, you can do as below:

```
getFileContentAsBase64(FILE_URI, callback) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, gotFile, fail);
  function fail(e) {
    alert('Cannot found requested file');
  }
  function gotFile(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        var content = this.result;
        callback(content);
      };
      // The most important point, use the readAsDatURL Method from the file plugin
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }
}
```

This returns a promise, to get your base64 data :

```
this.getFileContentAsBase64(thisResult.filename, (base64Image) => {              
            // Then you'll be able to handle the image file as base64
        });
```

**PS** : FILE_URI should look like file:///storage/0/android...